# Apache Spark: Can't resolve constructor StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've been trying to establish a StreamingContext in my program but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. I added the spark-streaming jar file to the dependencies and imported it in the code but I can't help feeling like I'm missing some small detail somewhere. How should I proceed?

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhqnZ.png)

Comment: can u share the codes

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import **StreamingContext** in your case.

Use

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
```

Not

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
```

It will import inner objects not the class.